# How to cut field in awk

Tags: awk, csh

I want to write script file to cut field and then use it to compare the field then print
ex: My input file

```
ADC1/asf/sd/df_adc1/125125
AED1/asf/sd/df_aed1/asfk
ASQ2/asf/df_asq2/aks
ABX5/df_abx5/asf/sd/sdgqw
```

Output file: The last field will print from beginning to the field have same the first but not capitalized. I will compare the first field and then find the word and print from begin to the word I had compare.

```
ADC1/asf/sd/df_adc1/125125     ADC1   ADC1/asf/sd/df_adc1
AED1/asf/sd/sf_aed1/asfk   AED1   AED1/asf/sd/sf_aed1
ASQ2/asf/dg_asq2/aks    ASQ2   ASQ2/asf/dg_asq2
ABX5/da_abx5/asf/sd/sdgqw  ABX5   ABX5/da_abx5
```

I had use awk to split :

```
awk '{split($1,a,"/"); {print $1, a[1]}}' input > output
```

and the output like that

```
ADC1/asf/sd/df_adc1/125125  ADC1
AED1/asf/sd/df_aed1/asfk   AED1
ASQ2/asf/df_asq2/aks      ASQ2   
ABX5/df_abx5/asf/sd/sdgqw  ABX5
```

but i dont know how to compare to make last field

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for editing it, looks like your last line `ABX5/da_abx5/asf/sd/sdgqw  ABX5   ABX5/da_abx5` has typo, isn't that should be like: `ABX5/df_abx5/asf/sd/sdgqw ABX5 ABX5/df_abx5/asf/sd/`?

Comment: no typo i just need print like if ABX5 i will need print from beginning to ....abx5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/" }
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i>1 && index(tolower($i),tolower($1))){
      print $0" "$1" "val OFS $i
    }
    val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/" }              ##Setting FS and OFS as / here.
{
  val=""                         ##Nullifying val here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){            ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if(i>1 && index(tolower($i),tolower($1))){  ##Checking if field is greater than 1 and  $1 is found in $i(current field) in case-insensitive mode then do following.
      print $0" "$1" "val OFS $i ##Printing current line first field val OFS and current field.
    }
    val=(val?val OFS:"")$i       ##Creating val which has val and current field value in it.
  }
}
'  Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the last field it not exactly what i need.
If the first field is ABX5 i just need print from beginning to the field have abx5.
Same with another line

Comment: @masifq, ok, so you mean when a line starts from `ABX5` then you need to print 2 fields and if not then print values till last occurrence of `/`? Please confirm once.

Comment: all line i need print from the beginning to the not capitalized of same line start
ex: ABX5 i will print from beginning to ....abx5,
    ADC1 i will print from beginning to ... adc1,
    ASQ2 i will print from beginning to ... asq2,

Comment: @masifq, I am sorry its really not clear still. So you mean you want to check if a line starts from capital letter? Just mention how last line in your output is different from rest of lines, with logic of how you are getting them.

Comment: I will compare the first field and then find the word and print from begin to the word i had compare

Comment: @masifq, Ok got it, please do check my edited code once and let me know if this helps you? Just now edited it, refresh your page once before using new solution.